# Ошибка доступа к файлу UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Здравствуйте. Перепробовал уже кучу способов: сначала на основе путей пробовал, потом на основе StorageFile-ов, но всё никак не получается получить доступ к файлам в папке, выбранной через FolderPicker.
Вот код, строчка в которой возникает ошибка доступа на запись в самом конце. Я уже учёл некоторые нюансы работы с файловой системой и объектами, не использую вообще никаких путей. Неужели FolderPicker и его StorageFolder не содержит в себе StorageFile-ы с полным доступом к ним?

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FolderPicker _folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
            _folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
            _folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
            _folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
            _folder = await _folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            if (_folder != null)
            {
                StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", _folder);
            }

            QueryOptions _queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, new[] { ".mp3" });
            _queryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
            var _queryResult = _folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(_queryOptions);
            _filesInFolder = await _queryResult.GetFilesAsync(); 

            foreach (StorageFile _file in _filesInFolder)
            {
                _audioList.Add(_file.Name);
                listView.Items.Add(_file.DisplayName);
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
        }
        listView.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private async void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (taglist != null) { taglist.Items.Clear(); }

        _index = listView.SelectedIndex;

        Stream _fileStreamRead = await _filesInFolder[_index].OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        Stream _fileStreamWrite = await _filesInFolder[_index].OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что пикер даёт доступ только к самой папке, а не ко всем подпапкам. Запрос с подпапками, скорее всего, работает только в "библиотеках". Соответственно, чтобы по папке можно было ходить рекурсивно, можно добавить её в библиотеку музыки.

Comment: Так в том и дело что доступ ко всем файлам есть, но только для чтения. Стрим чтения открывается к любому файлу. И даже можно создавать свои файлы в любой папке внутри выбранной. Можно удалять, копировать любые файлы оттуда. Но открыть поток для записи нельзя даже к созданному программой файлу. Что за бред?

Comment: А что вы конкретно делаете, и что происходит? Какой код запускается? Если можно, уберите из кода всё лишнее (например, `button1_Click` точно не нужно).